# dynamodb: provision more capacity during set hours

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, provisioning

Assuming that 90% of writes occur between 05:00 and 07:00 every day. Is there a way to provision more capacity from 4am to 7am so that AWS can be ready for those writes and that I don't have to spend the write capacity money during the rest of the day?

Answer (score 0):

Use [updateTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property) function from AWS-SDK for DynamoDB.

Also check out "Semi-Homemade Autoscaling" section in [this article](http://0x74696d.com/posts/falling-in-and-out-of-love-with-dynamodb-part-ii). It has some real-life experience on auto scaling DynamoDB and a listing of the Python script they used to change DynamoDB provisioning.